# Get parametervalues from ParametricPlot?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

From an examplary plot

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{1 Cos[s] , 2 Sin[s]}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I know how to get the plotted points

```
pi = Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity][[1]];
```

Additionally I would like to get the parametervalues `s` (automatically used by `ParametricPlot`) of the plotted points `pi`: `{s[i],p[i]}`

How to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: for the specific example, `angles = First@Cases[pp, Line[x_] :> ArcTan @@@ x, All]`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, the example seems to be to easy. How to proceed if you don't know the context  between `Point` and `Parameter`?

Comment: would this be cheating: `f[s_] = {1 Cos[s], 2 Sin[s]};
{plot, evals} = 
  Reap[Block[{e = 0}, 
    ParametricPlot[f[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[Tooltip[{Opacity[0], Point[f@s]}, s]]]]];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, evals}]]`?

Comment: @kglr `ParametricPlot` uses a set of parametervalues `s[ i]` for every plotted point `p[i]`. Unfortunately `plot` doesn't keep this context.

Comment: .. that is, we can't even  identify the min and max of the parameter from plotted points.

Comment: Yes that's clear.  But the plotted curve uses a set of points automatically choosen by `ParametricPlot` and I wish to get the used corresponding parameter values of these points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modified an example from the `EvaluationMonitor` document.

```
f[s_] = {1 Cos[s], 2 Sin[s]};
{plot, evals2} = 
  Reap[ParametricPlot[f[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{s, f[s]}]]];
evals2
```

```
f[s_] = {1 Cos[s], 2 Sin[s]}; {plot, evals} = 
 Reap[Block[{e = 0}, 
   ParametricPlot[f[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[Tooltip[Point@f[s], s], ++e]]]];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, evals}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `evals` only give the plotted points,   but not the corresponding parametervalues `s` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  `Show[plot, Graphics[{Red, evals}]] // FullForm`  or  put your mouse in the figure.

Comment: How would I extract the tooltip values to a separate list?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  `evals2[[1, ;; , 1]] ==
 Cases[FullForm[evals], Tooltip[_, a_] :> a, Infinity]` return `True`

Answer (score 5):

```
f[s_] := {1 Cos[s], 2 Sin[s]}

{plot, slist} = Reap[ParametricPlot[f[Sow@s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}]];

Show[plot, 
 ListLinePlot[f /@ Sort[slist[[1]]], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[10],  Red]]]
```

[image]

```
g[s_] := {Sin[5 s], Sin[4 s]}
{plot, slist} = Reap[ParametricPlot[g[Sow@s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}]];

Show[plot, 
 ListLinePlot[g /@ Sort[slist[[1]]], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[10], Red]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** If we have a `Graphics` object for a curve generated by  `ParametricPlot` and know only the range of the parameter `s`, we can use a combination of `BSplineFunction`, `Nearest` and `Rescale` to reconstruct the  list of parameter values associated with line coordinates:

```
{smin, smax} = {0, 2 Pi};

f[s_] := {1 Cos[s], 2 Sin[s]};

plotf = ParametricPlot[f[s], {s, smin, smax}, ImageSize -> 400];

coordsf = Cases[plotf, Line[x_] :> x, All][[1]];

bSFf = BSplineFunction[coordsf];

slistf = Rescale[
  Values @ Association[
    SortBy[Nearest[coordsf][bSFf @ #][[1]] -> # & /@ Subdivide[4000], Last]], 
  {0, 1}, {smin, smax}];

Show[plotf, 
 ListLinePlot[f /@ Sort[slistf], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[10], Red]]]
```

[image]

```
g[s_] := {Sin[5 s], Sin[4 s]}

plotg = ParametricPlot[g[s], {s, smin, smax}, ImageSize -> 400];

coordsg = Cases[plotg, Line[x_] :> x, All][[1]];

bSFg = BSplineFunction[coordsg];

slistg = Rescale[
  Values @ Association[
    SortBy[Nearest[coordsg][bSFg @ #][[1]] -> # & /@ Subdivide[4000], Last]], 
  {0, 1}, {smin, smax}];

Show[plotg, 
 ListLinePlot[g /@ Sort[slistg], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[10], Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: That's it , thank you! Surprisingly `slist (* {{0, 0.000128228, s, 0., 0.12333, 0.257035...}}  *)` starts with symbol  `s` at the third position?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, interesting; no idea why `s` is there.